# CSRF token mismatch with laravel and pusher

Tags: laravel, pusher

I implemented pusher into laravel and I get an error a few times a day with a csrf token mismatch.  It comes from a request with the following and gets the error below.

```
   "path": "broadcasting/auth",
    "request": {
        "socket_id": "9057.89308",
        "channel_name": "private-App.User.122"
    },
    "action": "\\Illuminate\\Broadcasting\\BroadcastController@authenticate"
```

The Error Below

```
"message": "CSRF token mismatch.",
    "context": {
        "errorLine": 84,
        "errorFile": "/var/www/html/Customer_Interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php",
        "error_catch_scope": "report",
        "error_catch_file": "/var/www/html/Customer_Interface/app/Exceptions/Handler.php"
    },
    "level": 400,
    "level_name": "ERROR"
```

Comment: could it be from a crawler?

Comment: it appears to be only from user, i see other logs with the exact user agent and the person's username.  I think I am going to just suppress this error if can figure out how to filter it.